# Can I hide a HTML tag by the content/value it contains?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm attempting to hide a h1 tag from one page, now it's a dynamic page so their are not any hooks that I can target. I was hoping their would be a quick fix from CSS to target the content.

I've done some research and attempted the following methods:

```
<div id="pageH1">
<h1>value</h1>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>


h1[att~=value] {
    display:none;
}

h1[att=value] {
    display:none;
}
```

However neither have worked, I was wondering if this was something that can be done with CSS or will I need to use JS?

Comment: There is no such selector, you'll need to use JS.

Comment: @Tommi, carefull, see :empty css selector

Comment: If I understand OP issue correctly, he wants to use selector for query `<h1>randomvalue</h1>`. `:empty` will not help in this case. Also it not so related to question in topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this via CSS, This may become a feature of CSS4, but does not work as of CSS3.

You will have do this via javascript.

Here is a simple jQuery example. ([View the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Yk4N/))

```
$('h1:contains("value")').hide(); // Hide any h1 element that contains "value"
```

The above code will match **ALL** of the following lines.

```
<!-- All three h1 tags will be matched -->
<h1>value<h1>
<h1>value #2<h1>
<h1>This is another h1 with "value" #3</h1>
```

You could add a `.no-hide` class and do the following:

```
// Hide all h1 tags with value, EXCEPT .no-hide
$('h1:contains("value"):not(.no-hide)').hide();
```

This would result in:

```
<h1>value</h1>                                             <!-- Hidden -->
<h1>value #2</                                             <!-- Hidden -->
<h1>This is another h1 with "value" #3</h1>                <!-- Hidden -->
<h1 class="no-hide">This has value but will not hide</h1>  <!-- NOT Hidden -->
```

Doing what you require in `pure CSS` is currently impossible (to my knowledge *Correct me if im wrong*).

Answer (score 0):

While no CSS solution exists, a simple JavaScript function may solve your problem

```
function forContent (selector, content, action) {
  [].forEach.call (document.querySelectorAll (selector), function (h) {
    (content === null ||
     typeof content == 'function' && content (h.innerHTML) ||
     typeof content == 'string' && content == h.innerHTML ||
     content.test && content.test (h.innerHTML)) && action (h);
  });
}
```

See the sample fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/uL9DZ/

Answer (score 0):

**:empty**

There is to be a css selector .. we hope, will be approved soon.

- [:empty on w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#empty-pseudo)
- [:empty on google](https://www.google.ca/#gs_rn=21&gs_ri=psy-ab&cp=11&gs_id=72&xhr=t&q=css+empty+selector)
- [css selector empty on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css%20selector%20empty)
- [:empty support on sitepoint (support reference)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-empty)

For your situation, i don't recommend using :empty **yet**.

I'd use jQuery.

```
if ($('#element').is(':empty')){
  //your coding
}
```

or

```
if ($('h1').is(':empty')){
  //your coding
}
```

---

Just apply a routine for 'each'  to be 'removed' if empty.

```
$( 'h1:empty' ).remove(); /* take the h1 OUT of the DOM */
```

or

```
$( 'h1:empty' ).hide(); /* display:none, visibility:hidden, opacity:0 */
```

Comment: Selectors 3, which includes `:empty`, has been a [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors) for over a year now. I'm not sure why you're linking to the editor's draft of that spec.

Comment: TY BoltClock, i made a correction.

Answer (score -3):

You can use visibility as hidden
like

h1

{

visibility:hidden;

}

by using this u can hide h1 tag.....

Comment: But you won't be able to display the tag based on its content.